# Trying to close the camera with a button using opencv and tkinter

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I have it so the camera is linked to the first button, and when you click that, it should open the camera. I'm also attempting to create another button that when you click that, it will close the camera. How is that suppose to work? I am using opencv, tkinter, and PIL.

Here is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk


white       = "#ffffff"
lightBlue2  = "#adc5ed"
font        = "Constantia"
WIDTH       = 1920
HEIGHT      = 1080
fontButtons = (font, 12)
maxWidth    = 1000
maxHeight   = 600
mainWindow = Tk()
mainWindow.title('RocketShip')
mainWindow.configure(width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT, bg="black")
mainFrame = Frame(mainWindow, height = 640, width = 810)
mainFrame.place(x=350,y=0)
cameraFrame = Frame(mainWindow, height = 640, width = 405)
cameraFrame.place(x = 0, y = 0)
lmain = Label(mainFrame)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)    

def show_frame():
    lmain = Label(mainFrame)
    ret, frame = cap.read()    
    cv2image   = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)    
    img   = Image.fromarray(cv2image).resize((810,640))
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)    
    lmain.grid(row=0, column=0)    

    lmain.grid(row=0, column=0)    
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk    
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)    
    lmain.after(10, show_frame)







#Buttons
TurnCameraOn = Button(cameraFrame, width = 405, height = 25, bg = "blue", command = show_frame)
TurnCameraOn.place(x = 0, y = 0)
TurnCameraOff = Button(cameraFrame, width = 405, height = 25, bg = "blue")
TurnCameraOff.place(x = 0, y = 300)

#file menu    
menubar = Menu(mainWindow)    
file = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)    
menubar.add_cascade(label ='Commands', menu = file)    
file.add_command(label ='Open Camera', command = show_frame)     
file.add_separator()    
file.add_command(label ='Exit', command = lambda:mainWindow.destroy())    
mainWindow.config(menu = menubar)    
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a flag. Set the flag to `True` when you want the camera to start and set it to `False` when you want to stop the loop, then use `VideoCapture.release()` to close the capturing device.

Here is an example

```py
import cv2
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


cam_on = False
cap = None
mainWindow = Tk()


mainFrame = Frame(mainWindow, height = 640, width = 810)
mainFrame.place(x=350,y=0)

cameraFrame = Frame(mainWindow, height = 640, width = 405)
cameraFrame.place(x = 0, y = 0)
   

def show_frame():

    if cam_on:

        ret, frame = cap.read()    

        if ret:
            cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)    
            img = Image.fromarray(cv2image).resize((810,640))
            imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)        
            vid_lbl.imgtk = imgtk    
            vid_lbl.configure(image=imgtk)    
        
        vid_lbl.after(10, show_frame)

def start_vid():
    global cam_on, cap
    stop_vid()
    cam_on = True
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
    show_frame()

def stop_vid():
    global cam_on
    cam_on = False
    
    if cap:
        cap.release()

vid_lbl = Label(mainFrame)
vid_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)

#Buttons
TurnCameraOn = Button(cameraFrame, text="start Video", bg = "blue", command=start_vid)
TurnCameraOn.place(x = 0, y = 0)
TurnCameraOff = Button(cameraFrame, text="stop Video", bg = "blue", command=stop_vid)
TurnCameraOff.place(x = 0, y = 300)

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: I notice when I stop the camera, it just freezes the last current image. Is there a way I could like put like a black screen over it?

Comment: @PandaMan456_ yes, if you simply want to remove the image use `vid_lbl.config(image="")` after the `cap.release()`. Else if you want a black screen, create a black image and use the same.

Comment: I've noticed that when I click the start button, theres about a 10 second delay before the actual camera starts. Is there a way I can reduce the time?

Comment: @PandaMan456_ You might want to try starting it in another thread. Btw, that delay isn't that significant, that you would want to start another thread.

Comment: @Art It wouldn't be a bad idea to add `cap = None` to the end of `stop_vid`.